# как растянуть высоту сайдбара на высоту контента

Tags: html, css

```css
.wrapper {min-height:100%;position:relative;}
.sidebar {background:#000;height:100%;}
.content {background:#eee;}
.col-sm-2 {width: 16.66666667%;float:left;}
.col-sm-10 {width: 83.33333333%;float:right}
```

```html
 <div class="wrapper">
         <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-sm-2 sidebar">
                  <ul class="sidenav">
                    ....
                  </ul>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-10 content" style="height:1000px;">
                  <div class="center__content">
                     <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-sm-12">
                           content
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
```

Как растянуть sidebar на всю страницу? Чтобы черный фон был до конца страницы. (height:100vh не то.) Кучу вариантов уже перепробовал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

приблизительные такие стили я б дописал к .row `.row{display:flex; flex-direction: row;justify-content: flex-end;}` и от .sidebar убрал висоту `.sidebar {background:#000;}`

Comment: Ваш ответ слишком неподробный, приведите пример использования

Answer (score 2):

```css
.wrapper {min-height:100%;position:relative;}
.sidebar {background:#000;height:100%;}
.content {background:#eee;}
.col-sm-2 {display: table-cell; height: 100%; width: 16.66666667%;}
.col-sm-10 {display: table-cell; width: 83.33333333%;}

.wrapper .row {display: table; width: 100%;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
         <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-sm-2 sidebar">
                  <ul class="sidenav">
                    ....
                  </ul>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-10 content" style="height:1000px;">
                  <div class="center__content">
                     <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-sm-12">
                           content
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.wrapper {min-height:100%;position:relative;}
.sidebar {background:#000;height:100%;}
.content {background:#eee;}
.col-sm-2 {width: 16.66666667%; position: absolute; top:0;left:0;bottom:0;}
.col-sm-10 {}


.wrapper .row {position:relative; padding-left: 16.66666667%;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
         <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-sm-2 sidebar">
                  <ul class="sidenav">
                    ....
                  </ul>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-10 content" style="height:1000px;">
                  <div class="center__content">
                     <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-sm-12">
                           content
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
```